# Child Class Attribute error

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a child (extended) class with a protected attribute height. 
I want to access it in the main program:

```
   while(line != null)
     {
        String[] field = line.split("#");
        int height = Integer.parseInt(field[0]);

        if (field.length ==1)
        {
           forest[cnt] = new Trees(height);
        }
        else
        {
           forest[cnt] = new Shrub(height, field[1]);

        }

        cnt++;
        line = inS.readLine();

     }
     inS.close();

     String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name to search for");

     for(int i = 0; i<forest.length; i++)
     {

        if (forest[i] instanceof Shrub)
        {
           String a = forest[i].getName();      
           System.out.println ("Found");
        }
     }
  }
```

However I get an error saying that it cannot find the method getName, however when i run the lol Shrub it works fine?

Thanks.

Comment: Try typecasting like this..`String a = ((Shrub)forest[i]).getName();`. This is because I don't think `getName()` method exists in the parent type. In such cases you should tell the compiler about it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Private access modifier methods are not accessible in child class. Make them Public or Protected.

Comment: public String getName()
      {
         return name;
      }

Comment: it is public, the method that is and the attribute is protected.